# nginx rewrite URL decoding first encoded character in URI

Tags: nginx

I have rules like the following:

```
location /trk/ {
    if ($args ~ "url=(.*)" ) {
        set $url $1;
        rewrite click.gif$ $url? redirect;
        rewrite redirect.gif$ $url? redirect;
    }
}
```

The problem is if I have a request like:

```
http://bar.com/trk/click.gif?some_foo&url=http://foo.com/%3Fmore_foo%3F
```

it gets rewritten to

```
http://foo.com/?more_foo%3F
```

and I need the first `%3F` to not get decoded to ?

It appears to decode the FIRST and only the first encoded character it finds.

I'm using nginx version 1.1.13

Comment: Also tried nginx version 1.3.2 as well as the latest 1.5.10 and get the same result - ideas anyone?

Comment: I still haven't figured this out - help anyone please?

Comment: I've solved this by rewriting the above using something like:        location /trk/click.gif {
            if ($args ~ "url=(.*)" ) {
                return 302 $1;
            }
            empty_gif;
            expires     0;
            add_header  Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        }

Comment: If you solved your own question, please write up a fully explained answer as a proper answer, so that the next person would know what's going on.

Comment: @JerryHoffmeister I tagged your answer as *Not an Answer* , so I'll comment here in case it gets deleted before you see it.  Simply take your comment from July 1st 2014 and post THAT as an answer, instead of a *comment* so that people who find your questions in the *future* will see it easier. Who knows, someone might even give you an *upvote*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by rewriting the above using something like:

```
location /trk/click.gif { 
    if ($args ~ "url=(.*)" ) { 
        return 302 $1; 
    } 
    empty_gif; expires 0; add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"; 
}
```

Comment: His issue is that you "answered" your question in a comment.  Please take that comment and make it an answer, as you did for this answer.  As it stands *this* is not an answer, but a comment on a previous comment.

Comment: I took the liberty of moving your comment (from above) into your answer (as it was meant as an answer but merely posted as a comment). Like this other users can easily find the answer without having to search for it in the comments. @JerryHoffmeister: feel free to further update the (your) answer.

Comment: @Ralph Incoming declined flag for me, I guess :(

Comment: Ha, thanks :)  I know that's what I did but to try to comment further would be to try to reconstruct a 2.5 yr old memory and I'm more likely to get it wrong than right :)  I'll do better at "answering" myself in the future.  Where's all this upvotes???